# Magento 2 How to separate every product on products layout

Tags: magento2

I want to separate every product on products layout.

Now:

[image]

I want separate product:
[image]

Comment: Not Understandable !!

Comment: What is not understandable? Currently, products are displayed on one layout. I would like every product to be displayed in a separate beam.

Comment: I think your question is related to styles buddy. :)